# How can I get JSON data from Rallydev rest API without login

Tags: json, rally

What I'm trying to do is to get JSON data (whatever it is just make sure I can get anything is ok) from Rallydev without login to make sure that Rallydev is on. I tried several ways, but each way requires a username and password. Would anyone provide a URI for this? Thank you, Guys. Anything you give would be appreciated.

```
String url = "link";
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
String s = webResource.get(String.class);

try { 
    // check if RallyDev service is up
    if (s.contains("Hello it is now "))
        _log.information("RallyDev is working... at " + new Date());

} catch (Exception e) {
    _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.INTERNAL_ERROR, "RallyDev service might be down!!! in " + new Date(), e);
}
```

Comment: Nancy, welcome to StackOverflow! The best way to get good answers here is to write a terrific question. Today's your lucky day, because you say you've written some code already. Post that code here, and I'm sure people here will be happy to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, jmort253. I'm putting my code below:

Comment: String url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29";  
Client client = Client.create();  
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);  
String s = webResource.get(String.class);  
try {
// check if RallyDev service is up
if (s.contains("Hello it is now "))
 _log.information("RallyDev is working... at " + new Date());

} catch (Exception e) {
_log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.INTERNAL_ERROR, "RallyDev service might be down!!! in " + new Date(), e);
}

Comment: No no no. Use the **edit** link underneath your question :)  You're going to give everyone a headache ;)  Just paste the code in with your question.

Comment: Hi Jmort253, I'm embarrassed. It's my 1st time to do this. I'm wondering is there a way to put the code in format?

Comment: Just paste it in and someone here will fix it :)  You'll figure it out yourself once you've been here awhile. Good luck.

Comment: Got it... Great! i'll have to use this way to format it. Good! I'm learning and trying to make this happen!!!

Comment: <code>String url = "[link](http://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29)";<br/> Client client = Client.create();<br/> WebResource webResource = client.resource(url); <br/>String s = webResource.get(String.class);<br/> try { <br/>// check if RallyDev service is up<br/> if (s.contains("Hello it is now "))<br/> _log.information("RallyDev is working... at " + new Date());<br/> } catch (Exception e) {<br/> _log.error(ErrorCodeEnum.INTERNAL_ERROR, "RallyDev service might be down!!! in " + new Date(), e);<br/> }</code>

Comment: Thank you whoever posted my code. :-) I still do not know how you did this.

Comment: This may help you as well [How to Format Code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/155826).

Comment: Thanks, Jmort. Next time when I post a question i'll definitely try this. It's kind of fun!! Anyway, do you know how can I get enough reputation to chat or post a photo? :-)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges. Or search on [Meta SO - The Q&A site *about* StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so whether it's Jersey client or plain old HTTP GET against Rally, I'm coming back to my original comment that developing a Java app to do this is a bit overkill. You could accomplish the same thing with a one-line curl command in Linux:

```
  curl -u 'rallyuser@company.com:rallypassword' https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement.js?pagesize=1
```

A valid (Rally is up and responding) response to this might look like:

```
  {"QueryResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "33", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "TotalResultCount": 84, "StartIndex": 1, "PageSize": 1, "Results": [{"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "33", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678910.js", "_refObjectName": "My Story Name", "_type": "HierarchicalRequirement"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using Jersey Client to setup a REST connection in Java. Are you really needing to do this without providing credentials? You'll need to pass credentials of some sort as any query-able endpoint in Rally is going to require HTTP Basic Authentication.

If you are looking for the appropriate REST syntax and endpoints to formulate a valid query, you may wish to look at our Webservices API documentation on REST queries:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest.jsp

As an example, a valid REST URL to do a query and get back JSON-formatted results is as follows. A GET against the following sample URL queries user stories owned by user: user@company.com:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(Owner = "user@company.com")&pagesize=1

This would return the first matching User Story.

A simple example of accessing Rally REST services in Java is here:

http://www.rallydev.com/help/basic-rest-client-operations-java

And a full (alpha-release) Java REST API toolkit for Rally is here:

http://www.rallydev.com/developer/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

All of the above seems like a bit overkill for just finding out if the Rally service is up. You can subscribe to Rally's status updates via RSS at http://status.rallydev.com as a good way to stay apprised of system status information.

I hope this helps - if the answer is off-target, please provide some further clarifying comments and we'll do our best to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark. It's nice to have people to answer my question. :-) I think the URL with Email address as parameter should be helped. I'm going to try this right now. 10 mins ago I'll give a feedback.